# Is Google Billing necessary for accessing Google API & Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm Trying to access maps using *Maps JavaScript API* at Google Cloud Platform.

I got error

> You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at

Can we access Google API & Services without link Billing Account?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is necessary to enable billing to access Google API & Services.

Some Google APIs charge for usage, and you need to enable billing before you can start using these APIs. Enabling billing for the APIs that your projects use also has other advantages:

- Some APIs allow free usage up to a courtesy usage limit, and in some cases this free limit is increased when you enable billing. For some APIs, more services are available after you enable billing.

Billing is enabled at the project level, not the API level. If you enable billing for a project, then every billable API in that project is billed, based on the project's usage. All usage in a project is billed using the payment method that you specify, and you can change to a different method at any time. You cannot selectively enable billing for some APIs but not others; when you enable billing for a project, it applies to all the APIs that you used within that project, even if the API is currently disabled. Refer [APIs and billing](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158867?hl=en#:%7E:text=Some%20Google%20APIs%20charge%20for,use%20also%20has%20other%20advantages%3A&text=For%20some%20APIs%2C%20more%20services%20are%20available%20after%20you%20enable%20billing.) for information.

**NOTE :** In order for you to use Maps API or Places API, you will have to create a new account under USD because Google Maps Platform services cannot be billed through the same billing account as Google Cloud Platform services. In order to continue using Google Maps Platform, all customers with a billing account in INR will need to create a new billing account for Maps and then migrate their existing Maps projects under this new account. You cannot get Google Map API without billing. Refer [Google Maps Platform](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-india-faq#bill-why) for information.